# How to choose Hadoop tools for faster performance

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hbase

I am confused to decide the technology and methodology to solve my problem.

I have 5000 test files that contains around 4TB of data that is being generated from the RDBMS and it takes around almost 4 days of time to prepare all 5k text files .To solve this time issue i am thinking to move all my 5k text files data into Hadoop system so that from there data can be read faster and text files can be generated at faster pace.

I have to do this activity for the first time after that data will be incremented but every month i have to generate 5k text files.

Usually i have to do full table scan and may have to perform some joins in order to prepare 5 K files.

Can any one please suggest which tool i should consider for this case .
MapReduce and HBase or HIVE table or something else .

Comment: Full table scan,use HIVE.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear what you are trying to do, since you want to move the text files to Hadoop and then generate the text files? I'll try to answer with a few points to consider.

The approach you take and technologies you use, depend on a few factors, such as  how you want to use your data: Export all of it to another system? Do analytics? Do random-access reads on small parts of the data? Or just archive it eg for legal requirements?

Some options for importing data:

1. If the input data is already text files and they are of a well defined structure (eg delimited) then you can move them into HDFS directly and create a Hive external table to read them when needed. This should be quicker to implement than other methods.
2. If the input is text files but the structure is difficult to deal with using Hive QL, consider using Spark to import, reformat, and export the data. Then perhaps store the data on HDFS as a delimited file if you want to use if from Hive, or you can load it into HBase.
3. If the input data is from RDMS and you have access to the RDMS: Either Hive or Spark can be used - look into Spark JDBC. Hive will be simpler but with less flexibility if you want to transform your data. Adding on simple dimension information using joins can be done in Hive. Spark code gives a higher flexibility if your data isn't easy to join, but is more complex to write. Spark can also handle real-time streaming which is useful if your source generates streaming data.
4. To do complex transformations on the data that may be difficult to do in Hive, or require multiple passes of the data (slow) then consider using Spark, which does in-memory processing. Spark can be quick to manipulate data - adding on dimensions & formatting the data is quick and flexible to do. The downside is you would need to develop & maintain custom code to do this, eg in Java, Python or Scala. Once transformed, you can write your data to HDFS as a delimited file if you want to access it from Hive. Or, load to HBase if you want quick, random access to the data.
5. Sqoop is an option if you want to extract from RDMS and the extract logic is fairly simple (eg extract based on Updated_date column). Sqoop is not very customisable, so anything more complex than that and you should consider the other options

Some options for using data:

1. Hive gives you a SQL-like language which may be easier to use if your team or end users are familiar with SQL. Hive can do joins, summaries etc. You can schedule these to run daily/weekly/monthly with Oozie. Note that Hive executes a MapReduce job on the cluster, which is like a "batch" running on the disk on each node. Not good for quick interactive queries, but good for processing large portions of data at once. It sounds to me like you might want to do batch-like processing. You can also give analyst users access to Hive to do analytics on the tables you've defined. Lastly, you can connect to Hive from Excel using ODBC which can be very useful depending on your use case.
2. HBase is a good option for quick, random access to massive data. Eg looking up one customer's information from millions of customers. However doing analytics across an HBase table is less desirable since HBase will not do full table scans as efficiently as Hive.
3. A hybrid option: you could store the data in HBase and create a Hive external table if you want to do occasional batch queries and have random-access via HBase. The Hive queries will generally be slower, due to using HBase scans, than if you had used a delimited file instead of HBase.
4. If you don't want to add on the lookup information to every record, and using Hive isn't desirable because you want random-access, consider using Storm DRPC to add on the dimensions on-the-fly when the data is requested. This works well for random access to the data, where it is less efficient to store all dimensional information in HDFS for every record. More complex and more flexible than doing the same with Hive.

Comment: Thanks for your Details explanation.I have structured 5K text files properly delimited .Size of such files are 4TB.I have decided to go for HBase bulk upload .HBase is because later i have to do update and delete also bulk is one time job.And then integrated HBase with HIVE so i can perform join and full table scan .

Comment: If the files are delimited, you could just move them into HDFS and create a Hive external view over them.
This will be quicker and simpler than HBase bulk loading - and quicker and simpler to do a scan and a join.

Comment: i have delimited data but i have incremental data also that will come as xml files .HIVE will be able to handle incemental data also ?